# Mapping items fetched from API javascript

Tags: javascript, api, async-await, constructor

I am trying to map some items returned to me from a API using a class and constructor with javascript.

My question is what I am doing wrong, since the log before the mapping "Result before Map" logs out my array of items. But after my map I get nothing and everything in my constructor is undefined.

```
class Test {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.testValue = obj.testValue
  }
}

async function getItems() {
  const promises = []

  const response = (await fetch(url)).json()
  promises.push(response)

  const result = await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log('Result before Map:', result)
  const tests = result.map(test => new Test(test))
  console.log('Result after Map:', tests)
}
```

Comment: just make sure your result object contains `testValue` property

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I dont really understand what you mean

Comment: Please show us the output that you get

Comment: Why are you pushing _one_ fetch response into an array, and then using `Promise.all` on the array. Can you just do a fetch, and loop over the data?

Comment: When calling the API I will get a array of 20 items in it. Thats all I want

Comment: Each Item is a object with multiple parameters, not showing those in the example because it really doesnt matter.

Comment: My point is: why are you pushing _that_ array into a _new_ array? It's unnecessary. `await` the response, `await` the JSON parsing, then just `map` over that array. No need for `Promise.all`.

Comment: Oh, I understand, I will correct this! Thanks!

Comment: That was the problem, no need to push into a new array. I just awaited the actual response and mapped it directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have one too many "await"s in there.

```
async function getItems() {
    const promises = []
    promises.push(fetch(url));

    const result = await Promise.all(promises)
        .map((r) => r.json());
    console.log('Result before Map:', result)
    const tests = result.map((t) => new Test(t))
    console.log('Result after Map:', tests)
}
```

The question is where "url" comes from. Currently there is no reference to url and even if, then it is just a single url. Maybe you're looking for something like:

```
async function getItems(urls) {
    const promises = urls.map((u) => fetch(u));
    const result = await Promise.all(promises)
        .map((r) => r.json());
    console.log('Result before Map:', result)
    const tests = result.map((t) => new Test(t))
    console.log('Result after Map:', tests)
}
```

Comment: The URL is a saved constant above my code example with a API request that returns an array of 20 objects with items in it

Comment: Ok. In that case, my last example should work just fine. Just replace "urls" with "url" and you should be fine

Comment: "*then it is just a single url*" - yes. Please also show the code for handling that (without any `map` and `Promise.all`) in your answer

Answer (score 0):

With a single url, it would just be

```
async function getItem(url) {
    const result = await fetch(url);
    const resJSON = result.json()
    console.log('Result before Map:', resJSON)
    const test = new Test(resJSON);
    console.log('Result after Map:', test)
}
```